# Docker on MacOS, unable to bind Postgres to port 5432

Tags: postgresql, macos, docker, docker-compose

Unsure if this is an issue with Docker for Mac, my Postgres installation (via Homebrew, or some other strange local issue going on.

Probably worth mentioning that I have never ran into this issue on Linux.

Here is a snippet from my `docker-compose.yml` file that uses the `postgres` image:

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=some_db
      - POSTGRES_USER=some_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

After starting compose services `docker-compose up`, I can see my postgres container running (`docker ps`).

I can also connect to it directly via `docker exec`

```sh
docker exec -it <container_id> psql -d some_db -U some_user
```

Everything working as expected so far...

However, when I try to connect to my Docker postgres instance via my local psql client:

```sh
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U some_user -d some_db
```

It is not connecting to the Docker instance of postgres and rather is trying to use my local postgres instance.

***Now the strange part...***

When I change the port binding in `docker-compose.yml`
from `5432:5432`

to `5433:5432` (5433 can be any open port)

I am able to connect to the Docker postgres instance as expected via my local psql client:

```sh
psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U some_user -d some_db
# After being prompted for my password I'm in!
```

I don't mind binding to a different port, but I'm still so curious what's happening here!

Anyone know what is happening?

- Am I just not able to bind to port 5432?
- Is this a Docker for Mac thing?
- Is there an issue in the way I installed Postgres?

Thanks!

Comment: On your docker-compose example, did you mean to use "5432:5432"? Else your question doesn't make much sense since you are publishing 5433.

Comment: Only one copy of a service can be listening on a given port, so if you have a non-Docker PostgreSQL listening on port 5432, you can’t also run a Docker PostgreSQL publishing the same port.

Comment: @codestation Good catch, sorry about that. Just updated the question!

Comment: @DavidMaze Wouldn't I not be able to start and run my postgres container at all in that case? While I have my local postgres instance running on port 5432, I am still able to run my postgres container (on 5432) and connect to it like so `psql -h <my_ip> -p 5432 -U some_user -d some_db`

Comment: If possible you have multi-ip for the host?